# how to include a file in HTML URL's query string while call python Request POST?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am in need of passing a image file as a query string in the URL while calling post from Python's request package. When this image is passed as an url it works. For example,

```
auth = {'app_id':'user_id','app_key':'user_key'}
url = 'https://api.kairos.com/v2/media'
queryParams = { "source": "http://static.goal.com/4321800/4321812_news.jpg"}
rply    = req.post(url, headers=auth, params = queryParams, verify=False)
```

The above code works. The url that is hit becomes

```
"https://api.kairos.com/v2/media?source=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.goal.com%2F4321800%2F4321812_news.jpg"
```

I have a need to replace the url passed as a value to key 'source' in queryParams. When I do this like below,

```
queryParams = { "source": "messi.jpg"}
```

I get an error saying "An invalid media URL was sent". The URL this time is,

```
https://api.kairos.com/v2/media?source=messi.jpg
```

When I try the same thing using cURL (as a debug), like below,

```
curl -X POST -H "app_id: user_id" -H "app_key: user_key" -F "source=@messi.jpg" "https://api.kairos.com/v2/media"
```

This works fine.
Now can anyone help me translate this cURL into python Requests POST call?

I had tried passing this file as 'files' in POST. Does not work either. It says source in URL missing. (Source is a mandatory query in URL). Wondering how to pass this file as value to this query 'source' in the url!!!

Comment: Use: `files={"source":open("messi.jpg", "rb")}`

Comment: Thanks Adam. That worked.